# Running maven in virtual box seems be causing issues with its libraries

Tags: linux, maven, java-8, maven-3

I am running maven 3.3.9 in virtual box with JDK8
and when I run the 'mvn' command from the terminal I get the following error:

```
constituent[25]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar
constituent[26]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/eclipse-aether-impl.jar
constituent[27]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guava.jar
constituent[28]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-lang3.jar
constituent[29]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-http-shaded.jar
constituent[30]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/javax.inject.jar
constituent[31]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-compat-3.x.jar
constituent[32]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-io.jar
constituent[33]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-interpolation.jar
constituent[34]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-lang.jar
constituent[35]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-utils.jar
constituent[36]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-cipher.jar
constituent[37]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-provider-api.jar
constituent[38]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-http-shared.jar
constituent[39]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/eclipse-aether-transport-wagon.jar
constituent[40]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/sisu-plexus.jar
constituent[41]: file:/usr/share/maven/conf/logging/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:545)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.inject.Provider
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 11 more
```

I read a few forums and they all suggest upgrading the JDK but I am already on the latest version. :-(

can someone please guide me with this issue.

The same version on windows machine works fine with same JDK

Comment: You're using virtualbox, but which OS image are you running? Impossible to reproduce your problem

Comment: I suspect your virtualbox's network is not configured properly and maven is not able to connect to repositories. Try installing this ( http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar ) manually in local repository.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Its Ubuntu

Comment: @Icarus3 I tried that as well. But what a weird thing that it spits out the same error even after that.

Comment: Can you show the full error output and not only excerpts...Furthermore a pom file would be helpful and which command you have used to run maven...

Comment: @khmarbaise That actually is almost the whole log, putting more info would only have some more excerpts. And I am using mvn clean install to run a web project but running mvn as well gives me the same error.

Comment: The are much more lines before etc. which can help here..

Comment: try "mvn -X ", then share that log with us.

Comment: @Icarus3 I re-installed the virtual box from scratch and it got the same error but this time when I copy pasted the .jar file from the link you provided maven commands started working fine. Sorry cant get the old logs. I saw comment after I did the whole set up again.